# Why does (3E)-3,4-dimethylhex-3-ene yield a meso dihalide when reacted with Br2/CCl4 at room temperature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

> [image]

The answer is B. But why? What makes it so different than the others?
I know that it attacks from the back (anti addition). But can't it do that for all and result in a meso compound?

Answer (score 4):

A **meso compound** is a molecule with multiple stereocenters that is superimposable on its mirror image. Meso compounds are easily identified by their internal plane of symmetry.

Using this knowledge, and given that $\ce{Br2}$ undergoes anti addition to alkenes, there are only really two answers that could possibly be meso compounds, **B** and **D**. Let us consider the products:

[image: Compounds]

Notice how only **B** has an internal plane of symmetry, and is therefore a meso compound.